# Does JPA need foreign keys

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Searched for quite a while but could not find the answer... So I ask here: 
Does JPA 2.0 (I am using OpenJPA with an oracle DB) really need any foreign key constraints in the DB?

I experimented quite a while with all kind of mappings (@OneToOne, @ManyToMany with and without extra join table, @ManyToOne, @OneToMany) and it worked till now with and without them. But I have read in some anwers here and out in the net that they are mandatory. So what is correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, foreign keys in the database are not strictly required. Neither when using JPA, nor when using (AFAIK) any other technology to access the database.

Foreign keys are there to prevent inconsistent data to be written to the database. If the software creating or updating the data in the database is already sane, the foreign keys will never be violated and you'll not notice if they are there or not.

Why do you think that foreign keys would be mandatory in combination with JPA?

Comment: They appear in a lot of tutorials and also a lot of mapping troubleshooting answers. And the latter have made me insecure if JPA does a good job without them...

Answer (score 2):

I guess the java JPA layer does not need them at all in order to generate the proxies, but discussing this is in fact potentially a flame war about production systems configuration.

If someone thought that they are mandatory (and I am one of those) it is probably not a JPA-related opinion but a database design principle.  Foreign keys enforce data consistence, and that can mean the world when operating a billing system or whatever logic you are implementing.  On the other hand, those who would not will probably hand performance arguments for that...  It is a matter of point of view